# Amazon Athena export compressed query (table)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

When I do a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

the output is saved in an Amazon S3 bucket as a plain CSV.

Is there an option to save the csv in a compressed format (gzip)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no output compression option (currently) available.

The only options are:

- Selecting the output bucket
- Encrypting query results